# How to xpath text() greater than number 1?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="ContentFooter ReadingContentFooter AnswerFooter" id="__w2_wFc2PGId125_content_footer">
  <span>1.6k views</span>
  <span>2 views</span>
  <span class="bullet"> · </span>
  <a class="VoterListModalLink" href="#" id="__w2_wFc2PGId130_modal_link">View 5 Upvoters</a>
</div>
```

I want to xpath

```
  <span>2 views</span>
```

which is greater than 1 view.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with XPath.

Comment: I thought you could do math operations in xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following HTML :

```
<div class="ContentFooter ReadingContentFooter AnswerFooter" id="__w2_wFc2PGId125_content_footer">
  <span>1.6k views</span>
  <span>1 view</span>
  <span>2 views</span>
  <span class="bullet"> · </span>
  <a class="VoterListModalLink" href="#" id="__w2_wFc2PGId130_modal_link">View 5 Upvoters</a>
</div>
```

The following XPath will select `span` elements with content greater than 1 (view) (`translate` and `substring-before` are used to clean the content of the `span` element before testing it):

```
//span[translate(substring-before(.,' '),'k','')>1]
```

Output :

```
  <span>1.6k views</span>
  <span>2 views</span>
```

**EDIT** : If you need to strenghten your XPath, you can go with :

```
//div[@id="__w2_wFc2PGId125_content_footer"]/span[starts-with(translate(.,"0123456789","¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤"),"¤")][contains(.,'view')][translate(substring-before(.," view"),"k","")>1]
```